# Default parameter file in navigation2

Tags: ros2, turtlebot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,
im searching for the default parameter file but could only find in `opt/ros/dashing/share/nav2_bringup/launch/nav2_params.yaml` some parameters but not the recovery plugin. I know the Turtlebot uses the  `Spin` recovery but i dont know where to change it. I'm trying to fine-tune my Turtlebot Burger from this [link](https://navigation.ros.org/configuration/params/tunable-params.html#).

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/353285/default-parameter-file-in-navigation2/) by [ROS2apprentice](https://answers.ros.org/users/54868/ros2apprentice/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2020-05-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Not all parameters are described in the params file. Any not included parameters will utilize the defaults set in the code.  You may tune any value in the documentation link by adding it to either that file (not recommended) or your own file you are version controlling.

PS: if you fine tune anything for the TB3, feel free to submit a PR with updates to that yaml file. We haven't done any excessive tuning yet for that platform.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-05-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ROS2apprentice](https://answers.ros.org/users/54868/ros2apprentice/) on 2020-05-27**:
Thanks! I don't know what PR means but i will post my tuning as an additional answer

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-05-27**:
PR means pull request. Its a way of submitting your updated parameters to the nav2 repository on GitHub for all users to use.

**Comment by [ROS2apprentice](https://answers.ros.org/users/54868/ros2apprentice/) on 2020-05-27**:
so there are two `.yaml` files that are used. One is `opt/ros/dashing/share/nav2_bringup/launch/nav2_params.yaml` the other one is in `/home/turtlebot3_ws/src/turtlebot3/turtlebot3/turtlebot3_navigation2/paramer`  the question is which one is the dominant one when one parameter is False and the other True? Also how can i disable a plugin like the ’spin’ recovery if i don't want to change the file in the `opt/ros/dashing` directory